# GlassFish v3 - portability of settings

Tags: java, glassfish, settings

Is there any way to simply copy the GlassFish v3.0.1 server settings (ie connection pools, resources, realms... ) to another GlassFish, so it is not needed to set them manually? This way it would be a lot easier to set up the **same** development environment.

Environment: NetBeans 6.9 + GlassFish 3.0.1

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should just be able to drop your `glassfish\domains\<name_of_domain>\config\domain.xml` file into your target domain and restart glassfish.

Comment: There is no `config.xml` file in that folder. I think you meant `domain.xml`, but that doesn't contain the whole config.

Comment: @wheelie - yes, I meant `domain.xml`. Can you be more explicit about what settings you have set that aren't captured in `domain.xml`? Looking at the one I have, connection pools, resources and realms are all specified.

Comment: I checked my `domain.xml` and only those pools, resources, realms are set there that are default. I installed GlassFish bundled with NetBeans 6.9; Does NetBeans "deploy" those resources from another config file when I start GlassFish from inside NetBeans?

Comment: I looked up `domain.xml` in the NetBeans configuration folder, and I found what I need under: `\Users\myUser\.netbeans\6.9\config\GF3\domain1\config\domain.xml`. Thanks Catchwa!

Comment: For me it seems that NetBeans does not create the GF3 folder from version 6.9.1, instead it saves the configuration to GlassFish install folder, as suggested in this answer.