# How to export setting of glassfish server to another glassfish server?

Tags: glassfish-3

How to save all the configuration of glassfish server to another glassfish server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this question: [GlassFish v3 - portability of settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857783/glassfish-v3-portability-of-settings)

the domain.xml in the glassfish\domains\\config\ directory contains resource, queue  information about the server.