# Extract GlassFish JDBC Connection Pool and Resource configuration to XML

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish

I have a Glassfish server running in which I configured a JDBC connection pool and a corresponding resource.
I configured them manually with the web interface, but I found that I could have configured them with an XML file as [this one](http://www.sdz-files.com/cours/java-ee/bonecp-datasource.xml) with the asadmin tool :

```
asadmin add-resource file.xml
```

Now that my resources are already configured, I want to extract this configuration to an XML file with something like :

```
asadmin get-resource-to-xml $resource_name $xml_filename
```

Is it possible to do this ? I looked in the [list of asadmin subcommands](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/GlassFish+Server+4.0+asadmin+Subcommands) but couldn't found one which would have this behavior ...

EDIT : I read that the information that I need may be in the following file :

```
glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml
```

Indeed, there's a `<resources>` category but it only contains the default pre-configured resources ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, even though I configured these resources from the web interface, the GlassFish server was always started by NetBeans, so the configuration information I need was in the NetBeans user directory, here :

```
$netbeans_directory/8.0/config/GF_4.0/domain1/config/domain.xml
```

I found the solution in the comments of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857783/glassfish-v3-portability-of-settings).